# epoll_event different initialization causes different epoll_wait results

Tags: c, linux, server, valgrind, epoll

Running the following snippet with valgrind:

```
struct epoll_event server_socket_conn_ev = {.events = EPOLLIN, .data.fd = server_socket};
//server_socket_conn_ev.data.ptr = NULL;
if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, server_socket, &server_socket_conn_ev) == -1) {
    perror(NULL);
    return 1;
}

struct epoll_event new_event;

while(1) {
    epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &new_event, 1, -1);
  ...
```

I get the following error:

```
==16219== Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==16219==    at 0x524AA7A: epoll_ctl (syscall-template.S:84)
==16219==    by 0x401464: run_server (server.c:85)
==16219==    by 0x401367: main (server.c:57)
==16219==  Address 0xfff0002e8 is on thread 1's stack
==16219==  in frame #1, created by run_server (server.c:69)
```

The fix here, is to uncomment the second line from the snippet. However, doing so gives me different results, specifically the variable *new_event*.

If do not not initialize data.ptr to NULL, then I got the following value for *new_event*:

```
(gdb) p new_event
$1 = {events = 1, data = {ptr = 0x3, fd = 3, u32 = 3, u64 = 3}}
```

as expected.

However, by initializing data.ptr = NULL, then *new_event* remains initialized after the wait call:

```
(gdb) p new_event
$1 = {events = 1, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}
```

1.) Why does this initialization affect the result of epoll_wait?

2.) How can I get rid of the valgrind error and get the results I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `new_event.data` is a *union*. That is to say, its various elements
   share the same storage. When you initialise data.ptr to `NULL`, that
   overwrites some (potentially *all*) the other fields (depending on
   your system, specifically what size pointers are).
2. Two options come to mind:

- (a) Configure valgrind to suppress the error, as it's arguably a false positive (valgrind doesn't know that it's OK to have some parts of that struct uninitialised)
- (b) Initialise the struct in a slightly longer-winded way:

`struct epoll_event server_socket_conn_ev = {.events = EPOLLIN, .ptr = NULL }; server_socket_conn_ev.fd = server_socket;`